# How to determine whether a running device is tablet or an Android TV in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to determine whether a running device is  tablet or an Android TV in Flutter?

Comment: To what purpose? Are you concerned with layout or with input mechanisms?

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called as [sizer](https://pub.dev/packages/sizer) you can use it to determine device type

```
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Sizer(
      builder: (context, orientation, deviceType) => MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (SizerUtil.deviceType == DeviceType.tablet) {
      return Container(width: 100.w, height: 50.h, color: Colors.red);
    } else {
      return Container(width: 60.w, height: 40.h, color: Colors.red);
    }
  }
}
```